# Find smallest subset prefixes

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Here is my code for this problem. I am using Trie tree for this solution, and wondering if any other better ideas in terms of better time complexity or space complexity. Also any bugs and code style advice are appreciated.

**Problem:**

> Given a set of strings, return the smallest subset of the given input word set --- that contains prefixes for every input words in the given input word set. The prefix should be a complete input word in the given input set, other than a prefix of a given word, For a word, which has no prefix,
>   return itself.
>
> If the list is ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf'] return ['foo', 'asdf']

The return is `foo` since `foo` is prefix for `foo` (itself), prefix for `foog` and prefix for `food` (in other words, `foo` could "represent" longer string like `foog` and `food`). Output also contains `asdf` because it is not prefix for any other words in the input list, so output itself.

The empty set is not a correct answer because it does not contain the longest possible prefixes.

**Source code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.isEnd = False
    def insert(self, word):
        node = self
        for w in word:
            node = node.children[w]
        node.isEnd = True
    def find_prefix(self, prefix, result):
        if self.isEnd:
            result.append(prefix[:])
            return
        for k,v in self.children.items():
            prefix.append(k)
            v.find_prefix(prefix, result)
            prefix.pop(-1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
    root = TrieNode()
    for w in words:
        root.insert(w)
    result = []
    root.find_prefix([], result)
    print result
```

Comment: I find your problem description unclear. Why not just return the entire input set--one of those is the longest possible prefix for any given word.

Comment: The problem is ill-formulated: eg what is the expected output for `[fab, fabc, fbc]`? Is it `[fab, fbc]` or just `[f]`? (how 'common' the 'common prefix' should be? Is it enough to be shared by only 2 elements or if it shared by more than two then 'commonality' take precedence over 'maximal length'?)

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I need to return the smallest set, which is the prefix for all input words. I edit the question description as well, please feel free to correct if still not clear. Your advice on original questions are highly appreciated.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, thanks for the comments, I have edit the question to make it more clear. In your example, `[fab, fbc]` should be returned, since `f` is not a separate word in the input set. Please feel free to advise if still anything unclear. Your advice on original questions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, so not only the common prefix but an entire word that is the common prefix of others?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, yes, I have just edit the post to adjust your comments to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is unambiguous.  (Maybe it was tougher before the edits).  The answer is that trie seems exactly right.

Build a trie from the input words, then traverse it depth first.  Each time you find a node (an inner node or a leaf) that's in the input set, add the word at that node to the output and cease searching it's children.

Comment: Thanks danh, wondering if other string based algorithm like KMP helps in your mind to improve time complexity?

Comment: That's a nice idea, but there's complexity  in comparing each word to all the others.  I'm too rusty to prove, but your current idea is O(n * average word length) where n is word count.  Using a clever string prefix tester, even if it's O(1) gives you O(n^2), where you compare each word to others to determine if it can stand in for them in the output

Comment: "I think the question is unambiguous." Really? What about `[f, fa, fab]`? After all, `fa` is a prefix for `fab`, so please quote ad litteram  the rule in the specification that is forbidding `fa` being listed as a prefix word.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, You had it right in comments. Because it is an input word and prefix to all the others, 'f' is the only output from that set. It's the "minimal subset" part of the spec that we rely upon

Comment: You're right, the minimal subset trumps the maximal prefix length.

Comment: @danh, nice catch. But I think my current implementation has limitation since it requires input words sorted by length (ascending), do you have any ideas using Trie or other solutions not requiring sorting the strings by length (ascending) as a pre-requisite?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, yes, I think danh catch the right problem statement. If you have any thoughts on the original problem and questions, it will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the simpler `while`-loop approach with a sort at the beginning:

```
minimal = []
words = ['foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf']
words.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
while words:
    word = words[0]
    minimal.append(word)
    words = [ x for x in words[1:] if not x.startswith(word) ]
print minimal
```

It is a fairly efficient implementation running in at worst O(n**2) when no string is a prefix of any other string.

---

Postscript #1: you can make the sort slightly more efficient by only sorting on the length of the words instead of both length and alphabetically.  e.g., changing this line:

```
    words.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x), x))
```

to:

```
    words.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
```

Of course a sort is O(n(log n)) which is the lower bound on the running-time/complexity.

---

Postscript #2:

If you prefer defined memory characteristics you can use marking instead of filtering on the `words` list.  A marking version of this algorithm would look like this:

```
    words = [ 'foo', 'foog', 'food', 'asdf' ]
    words.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))
    marked = [ False for _ in words ]
    for i in range(0, len(words)):
        is_marked = marked[i]
        if is_marked: continue 
        word = words[i]

        for j in range(i + 1, len(words)):
            if not marked[j] and words[j].startswith(word):
                marked[j] = True
    minimal = [ word for word, is_marked in zip(words, marked) if not is_marked ]
```

It is slightly more verbose than my preferred filtering version but has the benefit of not continually creating/destroying the words array in each successive pass of the loop.

Comment: Thanks 2ps, why you think your code is worst case `O(n**2)`? I think it is always `O(n**2)` since you compare each word pair? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong reading your logics.

Comment: Also another comments is, you are using `words` to control `while` loop and in the loop itself, you change the value of loop control variable `words`, not sure if it is a good idea? I am coming from C++/Java and common understanding is not touching loop control variable as a good practice. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa:  It looks like you didn’t follow the logic of the `while` loop correctly.  The algorithm does not compare each word pair.  After the first pass of the while loop, `'foo'`is compared with all the other words, and `'foog'` and `'food'` are filtered out of the words list.  So on the second (and final) pass of the `while` loop, `'asdf'` is added to the minimal set but is not compared to any other word.  QED.

Comment: @LinMa:  wrt loop control variables, even a very basic for loop in Java and C++ has a loop control variable that changes.  For example:  `for (x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {}` has a loop control variable that changes over the course of the loop.  A `while` loop that consumes items off an array is a standard pattern.  In this case, the while loop is guaranteed to end because in each iteration of the loop we are always consuming at least one word off of the words list.